# Get the file Attributes (client side) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application, I need to calculate the size of the file in **client** side (before uploading to server).

I want to restrict the file being  uploaded if it doesn't satisfy my requirements like file **size**, file **type**..

Is it possible to achieve this in client side using JavaScript?

Comment: If in .NET - this is one of the best tools I've used http://krystalware.com/Products/SlickUpload/. Blocking extensions, detecting file size, progress bar.. simply briliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In browsers with support for HTML5´s [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), you now can.

This is [true for updated browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29#Related_specifications), not surprisingly [IE excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349144/will-ie9-support-the-html5-file-api).

```
var files = $(this).attr('files');
var MAXFILESIZE = 500000; // bytes
if (files) {
    // <input type="file" multiple>
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        // We can also validate files[i].type or files[i].name vs an expected file type
        if (files[i].size > MAXFILESIZE) {
            alert('File "'+files[i].name+'" is too big.');
        }
    }
}
```

The future says "hello"! :)

Answer (score 4):

In the vast majority of current browsers, there is *no way* to accomplish this with **pure JS**. Some of the newer HTML5 file tools may allow for this, but their support is limited.

You will need to go with a **Flash based uploader** tool to get this data *before* upload. Check out [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/) to get you started.

I would suggest you implement it this way:

1. Take whatever precautions on the server you can to limit the upload size (Each server technology handles it a bit differently). *Always do this as client side controls can be bypassed*
2. Use a standard File Upload input element to start
3. Progressively enhance it using something like the YUI Uploader or Uploadify. That way it works faster on files that do not match for users with Flash, but it *also* works for normal uploads since it will also be checked on the server.

Comment: @patrick you are welcome! Man, I am just happy I beat you to an answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't practically possible ( maybe it is with some Java+ActiveX exploit in IE ) before actually submitting the file with a POST request to the server.

Comment: Thanks meder, I can cache the file type and test it using regular Expressions (just a Thought), but I still need to cache the file size, which is impossible for now  using JS, may be it might take some time to Implement in gathering all the attributes of a file using pure JS

Comment: Well, you can often determine file type by checking the file extension. That is possible using a little regexp on the filename.