# Will IE9 support the HTML5 File API?

Tags: internet-explorer, html

Will IE9 support the [HTML5 File API?](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

Comment: Probably. They'd be stupid NOT to.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)#Related_specifications

Comment: Why would they support an experimental/wip standard? Oh right, because the competition already does it. Well I'd rather they support what they should have than some experimental piece of crap pushed by some people that just do not have anything better to do *(points at Mozilla people)*. Thanks Mozilla, you gave us a browser that works worse than IE6 which supports experimental features. Great job.

Comment: lol! are you serious man... wow

Comment: @Christian Lay off the 'magical smoke'. Chrome, FF, Safari all have  stable File API support. Even Mobile Safari and Android provide partial support and they use special file systems. The reality is that this feature should be considered 'low hanging fruit' and MS is 2+ years behind the curve.

Comment: @EvanPlaice They support a non-standardized API, yet Android Browser, for instance, does not support Websockets - I a much more important feature than file access. For the record, safari pretty much blocks file api on most systems (windows/osx) and completely files on mobile devices (ipad/iphone).

Comment: @Christian Websockets != File API, don't change the subject. I'm calling BS. I just got a photo to successfully load on both Safari and Chrome in iOS. File API works on FF/Chrome in Windows, FF/Chromium in Linux, and according to caniuse.com Safari handles it in OSX too. Fact, the only mainstream browser it's guaranteed not to work on is IE. I'm invoking the MS fanboi-card. Go back to spreading FUD on Technet.

Comment: @EvanPlaice I'm no MS fanboy...I'm all for having a stable set of features common between browsers before jumping in the the hype wagon, as we're doing now. As I said earlier, I'm still waiting for browsers to support some major concepts, yet everyone's happy with hyped features such as the file api. Don't believe me? Go check when Firefox decided to support `text-overflow`...yet every other browser supported that attirbute - even MSIE.

Comment: @EvanPlaice Also, you're missing something crucial; *what is the file api*? Out of 5 significant pillars in the file api, safari is missing two. I know, I reported the problem to them as well as caniuse (a clarification on their charts). Just because you're happily playing with javascript that seems to work does not mean everything is fine and dandy out there. Firefox's file api implementation was the first between all browsers. Did you know they disabled the feature a version later, for two versions?

Comment: @EvanPlaice You seem to be missing the big picture, so I'll repeat one last time. The "problem" is browser vendors running before they can walk. This includes all friggin vendors, including MS. Did you know IE 10 is supporting some experimental API before other browsers? Did you also know it is missing some very basic CSS transformations? Well, finally MS ended in the same "lets do the cool stuff and worry later" wagon we're all used to know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't really look like it: I can't see anything in the [Internet Explorer 9 Beta Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff468705.aspx#_HTML5_Selection_APIs). True, it's not the final release yet, but you'd expect to see *something* about it in the Beta version if they were going to support it....

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) says "support unknown".

Comment: Reason #5639 no one should be using IE.

Answer (score 15):

Internet Explorer 9 (final) does not support the File API, but does support the Drag and Drop API.

Microsoft's "HTML5 Labs" incubator is [working on File API support](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2011/04/first-preview-of-internet-explorer-10-arrives-with-new-features.ars) and it is assumed that it will be in IE 10 most likely.

Answer (score 4):

IE10 starts supporting File API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx