# IE : empty "result" with Jquery File Upload Plugin

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, upload, jquery-file-upload

I have got a problem with the jQuery File Upload Plugin.

I want to get back some data's about the submitted file, so i use the `onDone: function (e, data)` callback.

I need to access to `data.result` to get the ID of the submited file, and inject it in a hidden file. Everything works great with Firefox, but when i tried on Internet Explorer, i found out that `data.result` was always empty.

Does anybody faced a similar issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE browsers less than version 10 don't have support for File API.

[Will IE9 support the HTML5 File API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349144/will-ie9-support-the-html5-file-api)

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand. According to the doc, it must support IE : http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload#browser_support - edit : my bad, it says : "Microsoft Internet Explorer has no support for multiple file selection or upload progress.". Thank you