# angular 4/5 cross browser file upload

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm creating an angular 4 app that has file upload as one of its features. I know that ng4 has support until IE 9 and I have created a working file upload component using FormData that is not supported back to IE9. Now what's the common way to create a cross browser solution to upload files that has support for older browsers as IE9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are very slim because IE9 did not ever put in much support for file uploads. So, in a nutshell, there is no common way.

See [this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349144/will-ie9-support-the-html5-file-api)